# How do I find the name of a descendant class if I'm in an ancestor method?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

We log our processes for debugging purposes, and use reflection to get the method name for logging.  Currently, I call the logging method with a parameter of System.Reflection.MethodInfo, and inside the logging method it parses that parameter to use Method.DeclaringType.Name to get the name of the class the method lives in (and also Method.Name, which isn't an issue at the moment).  What I get from this is the ancestor name, and I want the descendant (even though the method being used is not overridden and is run directly from the ancestor).  Is this possible?  I went scrounging through the reflection information but didn't find the descendant name anywhere.

I am not concerned about the performance issues of Reflection, and I'm willing to add additional parameters to the logger method if necessary to get the information I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `Method.ReflectedType.Name` do what you expect?

Comment: @cdhowie - in this case, they're identical.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you're not going to get that from the `MethodInfo`. You should pass in `this`, at which point the logging code can call `GetType()` to find the *actual* type of the object.

Comment: I'm assuming that the OP is getting this information from a `new StackTrace()` object... in that case, the actual type of the object (if any) associated with each stack frame might not be available at all.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes, that would certainly be the case. It's hard to say without more information.

Comment: No, I'm not using the new StackTrace object, and this solution works.  I was hoping not to have to make an override of the logger, but this is great.  Thanks!